# Generation of a dataframe with ratio in the trend

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe :

DF

```
Date_1      Date_2      b_count
01/09/2019  02/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  03/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  04/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  05/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  06/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  07/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  08/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  09/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  10/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  11/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  12/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  13/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  14/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  15/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  16/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  17/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  18/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  19/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  20/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  21/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  22/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  23/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  24/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  25/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  26/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  27/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  28/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  29/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  30/08/2019  148
01/09/2019  31/08/2019  148
```

I want to generate another column in dataframe individual_count which is to be created with the value of b_count i.e. 148 such that 60% of the count lies in the last 10 days and rest 40% within the remaining days. for example - here date_1 is repeated 30 times, 148 is to be divided in 30 entries such that 60% of the count lie in the last 10 dates of date_2 (in our case from 22/08/2019 to 31/08/2019.

So far, I was able to achieve the increasing trend using :

```
def add_series(grp):
   n_rows = grp.shape[0]
   val = grp['b_count'].min()
   s = np.exp(np.linspace(0,1,n_rows)) 
   s = np.round((s * val)/ np.sum(s))
   grp['individual_count'] = s
   return grp

df3 = joined_df.groupby('Date_1').apply(add_series)
```

This provides me the increasing trend in the allocation of individual_count, however, I also want to assign the 60-40 ratio,

So the idea is to incorporate the 60-40 ratio and consume complete count accordingly. Can anyone help with the same.

Please Note - the dataframe is already sorted first of Date_1 and then on Date_2.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you simplify your query?

Comment: @Sampath I didn't understand what you meant, but let me provide you an example. since there are 30 entries for each and every Date_1. I want to distribute the b_count in increasing way such that, 60% of the entries lie in the last 10 values of the dataframe and rest 40% in the remaining 20 days. Also, we need an increasing trend for distribution of b_count as well.

Comment: @ansev Can you take a look at this..

Comment: If possible, can you try to do these - 1. Show us a sample output 2. I see only 148 in b_count, can you take simpler smaller examples with different counts?

Comment: @Sampath The values in b_count are same corresponding to the date_1. Each date_1 has 30 values in dataframe corresponding to different date_2